# In this function, (speed) is the parameter, and what does the zero (0) do there?

Tags: javascript

```
this.moveRight = function(speed) {
   this.move(speed, 0);
};
```

I am new at Javascript, I just took this piece of code from one game, and I want to know what is happening with this function.

Comment: It's a parameter to the `move` method. Most likely, `move` takes an *x* and *y* parameter so `moveRight` is simpling moving along the positive-*x* axis. However, without seeing the `move` method, that's pure speculation.

Comment: The keyword `this` refers to the instantiated Object (could be an Object literal or Constructor called with the keyword `new` in front of it) which `moveRight` is being assigned to as a method, since it `= function(){}`. `moveRight` is being given a parameter `speed`, which is being passed into a method that already exists called `move` which already belongs to the Object that `moveRight` is being assigned to. You would have to look at `this.move = function(){}` inside a Constructor, or `move: function(){}` inside an Object, to see exactly what is happening with the `move` method.

Comment: reopen vote - question is pretty clearly clear.

Comment: @djechlin: Then what does the `0` do in the `.move()` code that the developer wrote? I sure can't tell, which is why I voted to close as having insufficient information.

Comment: @cookiemonster the question *exactly* asks *verbatim* "what does the zero (0) do there?" That *is* the question. What am I missing?

Comment: @djechlin: Are you suggesting he's literally asking about the syntax? As in he knows enough terminology to be able to describe `speed` as a *"parameter"*, but still doesn't know that `0` is just a second one? Possible I guess. *"Ask the right question"*

Comment: @cookiemonster I think that's exactly the question. OP is actually learning what a parameter is which is why it's spelled out in the question title. Probably learning the difference between a parameter in a function declaration v. in a function invocation - and the literal "0" is the first example that shows that they are different.

Comment: @djechlin: Yeah, could be. The last sentence in the question doesn't quite sound that way, but maybe that's the case. I'll vote to reopen in faith that OP is going to clarify the question.

Comment: @djechlin: Nope, looks like it was indeed asking about program code semantics, and not syntax. [What is going on with this function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751123/what-is-going-on-with-this-function)

Comment: @user: next time please edit your question in response to feedback instead of posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`speed` is the parameter to the `moveRight` function which you create with `function()`.
It calls the `move` function internally on `this` with parameters `speed` and `0`.

So `moveRight` is like a partial which provides a default parameter for `move`: `(0)` and retains the parameter `speed`.

`0` probably stands for the **right** direction.