# What is going on with this function?

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
this.moveLeft = function(speed)
    {
      speed *= -1; // Make speed a negative number
      this.move( speed, 0 );
    };
  this.moveUp = function(speed)
    {
      speed *= -1;
      this.move( 0, speed );
    };
 this.moveDown = function(speed)
    {
      this.move( 0, speed );
    };
 this.move = function( x, y ) 
    {
```

I am new at Javascript and took this piece of code from a game. I want to know what is happening here, in every functions. If I am not wrong there are 4 functions here and everyone with a parameter. Why move left and up is a negative number? And also, why zero (0) changes its position with the parameter "speed" when there is moving left and moving up?

Comment: See http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#coordinates. Imagine the object being in a Cartesian coordinate system. Then moving "left" means *decreasing* the `x` value the coordinate and moving "right" means increasing the `x` value. Similar for the `y` value, only that on a canvas the `y` acis is "flipped".

Answer (score 2):

> If I am not wrong there are 4 functions here and everyone with a parameter.

Correct, except `move` takes *two* parameters (arguments).

> Why move left and up is a negative number?

Because in browsers, the coordinates on the page start at 0,0 in the left,top of the page, the `x` increases as you move right, and the `y` increases as you move down. So to move "left" you reduce the `x` coordinate, and to move "up" you reduce the `y` coordinate.

> And also, why zero (0) changes its position with the parameter "speed" when there is moving left and moving up?

Because there are two coordinates, `x` (horizontal) and `y` (vertical). `moveLeft` moves left (reduces the horizontal, without changing the vertical, so the vertical is `0`). `moveUp` moves up (reduces the vertical without changing the horizontal, so the horizontal is `0`).

Answer (score 2):

> Why move left and up is a negative number?

Because the game works on an "inverted-grid":

[image: HTML canvas grid]

So while your intuition would say that UP is positive, it is in fact negative on this grid system. Left is always negative, i.e. if you are in (3, 0) and you move one unit left, you end up in (3 - 1, 0) = (2, 0).

> And also, why zero (0) changes its position with the parameter "speed" when there is moving left and moving up?

I am not sure about what you mean here but the speed is the number of units you move in a certain interval of time. In my example about (3, 0) => (2, 0), the speed is "1" (you move one unit).

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `this.move` takes two arguments:

1. The first one is the amount to be moved towards right
2. The second one is the amount to be moved towards bottom

Then,

- `this.moveLeft` moves `-speed` units towards right (i.e `speed` units towards left), and `0` units towards bottom.
- `this.moveUp` moves `0` units towards right, and `-speed` units towards bottom (i.e `speed` units towards top).
- `this.moveDown` moves `0` units towards right, and `speed` units towards bottom (i.e `speed` units towards top).

> Why move left and up is a negative number

Because multiplying a vector by `-1`, you get a vector of the same length but opposite direction.

> Why zero (0) changes its position with the parameter "speed" when there is moving left and moving up?

Because this way the scalar product of the vectors gives always 0, that is, they are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

The speed integer corresponds to the movement of the "character". So if 1 is north then -1 would be south.

So when passed into the `move()` function which has an x and y parameter:

`move(-1, 0)` Would move left

`move(1, 0)` Would move right

`move(0, -1)` Would move south

`move(0, 1)` Would move north